# how to set tableViewCell background to black gradient like navigationbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have set up my own custom tableViewCell and want to the background to be the same 
black gradient as my navigationBar with style UIBarStyleBlackOpaque.

what would be the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the key combination **CMD-SHIFT-4** to capture a 1 pixel wide image of the navigation bar's gradient. The image will be saved on your desktop (you can use Preview to crop, etc.). Add the image to your project. In `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, use:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blackGradient.png"]];
```

UIKit automatically stretches the gradient horizontally to fit the width of the cell.

Comment: you are right works like a charm! thanks! how does this effect performance ? are there better ways to do the same ?

Comment: Performance wise, it will definitely increase memory usage and GPU processing, but not enough for you to notice. There is `CAGradientLayer`, but you won't get exactly the same gradient that is used on the navigation bar, and the performance is about the same. Many apps out there, like Tumblr, use images.